# C# SqlConnection (IIS issue?) "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sqlconnection

I'm having quite an odd issue.

I have a C#/ASP.Net application that connects to an SQL database to retrieve information.

When I run it locally, it works perfectly. I'm able to retrieve data, no issues.

I tried to deploy it to an IIS server on my network, and I started to get an error: 
`The ConnectionString property has not been initialized`

This generally means that a variable hasn't been initialized/has no value, which is weird since it runs locally. I rebuilt, re-deployed, made sure I've got all the files, etc.

I decided to try something else - I added a section of code (the File.WriteAllText).

```
private DataTable getStoredProcResults(string procName, string[][] parameters)
    {
        InitSql(true);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\CONNECTION.LOG", connectionDetails.ConnectionString); //Added this
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionDetails.ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(procName, sqlConn);
            foreach (string[] param in parameters)
            {
                sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue(param[0], param[1]);
            }

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;



            da.Fill(dt);
            sqlConn.Dispose();
        }


        return dt;

    }
```

This is where it gets weird. I'm able to write out the connectionDetails.ConnectionString to a text file, and it has the correct value.
I've compared the value on the IIS web server to the text file when I run it locally, and the connection string is exactly the same.

**How is it able to write the connection string out to a text file, if the following line errors saying the ConnectionString isn't initialized?**

Here's the full error on the IIS server when I visit the page:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

Stack Trace:

```
   [InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand() +6610944
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,     TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +292
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +487
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +293
   GenericPortalWebForms.Logic.HourGlassJob.getResultSet(String sqlCommand, Boolean fromHourGlassDB) in c:\Users\cthompso\Source\Workspaces\CustomSolutions\Sema\GenericPortal\Hourglass\Web\Logic\HourGlassJob.cs:297
   GenericPortalWebForms.Logic.HourGlassJob.setJobDetails(Int64 wrID) in c:\Users\cthompso\Source\Workspaces\CustomSolutions\Sema\GenericPortal\Hourglass\Web\Logic\HourGlassJob.cs:75
   GenericPortalWebForms.Logic.HourGlassJob..ctor(DataRow hgJobRow) in c:\Users\cthompso\Source\Workspaces\CustomSolutions\Sema\GenericPortal\Hourglass\Web\Logic\HourGlassJob.cs:40
   GenericPortalWebForms.HourGlass.GetAllHGjobs() in c:\Users\cthompso\Source\Workspaces\CustomSolutions\Sema\GenericPortal\Hourglass\Web\Hourglass.aspx.cs:49
   GenericPortalWebForms.HourGlass.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\cthompso\Source\Workspaces\CustomSolutions\Sema\GenericPortal\Hourglass\Web\Hourglass.aspx.cs:26
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

============================================================

Edit: Sorry, my code is here:

When I first create the object I initialise it from the get go.

```
private ConnectionStringSettings connectionDetails = ConfigManager.HourglassDb;
```

From Config Manager:

```
public static ConnectionStringSettings HourglassDb
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName.Split(',')[2]]; }
    }
```

and from web.config:

```
<add key="ConnectionStringName" value="name=BLAH1,BLAH2,BLAH3,BLAH4" />
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BLAH3" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: How is the ***connectionDetails.ConnectionString*** value populated? The problem most likely is there but we don't see that code.

Comment: Apologies, added now. The ConnectionStringSettings are set from config manager, which returns a single connection string.

Comment: Could you reproduce this problem on a local IIS instance?

Comment: After reviewing your code I realized that the stacktrace you provided does not include getStoredProcResults-method, so the error is not happening where you think it is. Review the stacktrace and see where the error is actually happening. For example getResultSet-method? Is the connectionstring set there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the command object before calling the `connection`'s `Open()` method. So something like this:

```
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(procName, sqlConn);
sqlConn.Open();
```